# Displaying integer in a special hexadecimal format

Tags: c, arrays

i am again facing a formatting problem. I want to pass a port number (as integer) as parameter to a function (argv[]) and want to display it in a special format. In my actual case i want to display the port number 1234 in hexadecimal. I try it this way

```
int port = 1234;
char* _port = (char*)&port;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(port); i++) {
    printf("\\x%02x", _port[i]);
}
```

but it shows

```
\xffffffd2\x04\x00\x00
```

But i want it in format with leading zeros and 2 digits like

```
\x04\xd2
```

can you help me please?

EDIT: I changed it to

```
sizeof(port)-2
```

and it shows only 2 digits but in the wrong endian :S

Comment: `sizeof(_port)` doesn't have to be equal to `sizeof(*_port)`. Also you should read about [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), and consider that `char` will be [promoted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to `int` with *sign extension*.

Comment: I dont expect it to be eqal, an array is not a pointer. But i didnt get the point. I also know (little) about Endians but i dont know how to convert it thats why im asking this questin.

Comment: If the value was not 1234, but 34, should output be `\x22`?   If the value was 65536, should output be `\x01\x00\x00`?

Comment: Likely, but i also get into troubles in the next time because 0 characters should be avoided cause they cant be sent over the network in a stream (will be treaten 0 terminator) but its a long time until i am that far :P You really recognized what i am about to do, right? hahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most systems the size of `int` is four bytes, 32 bits. The hexadecimal representation of `1234` is `0x000004d2`. On a little-endian system (like x86 and x86-64) it's stored in memory like the four bytes `0xd2`, `0x04`, `0x00` and `0x00` *in that order*.

If we look at it as an array of bytes, it looks like

```
+------+------+------+------+
| 0xd2 | 0x04 | 0x00 | 0x00 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

There are three problems you have:

1. You loop over all *four* bytes of the `int`, while you only want the significant bits
2. You don't consider the endianness
3. That `char` on your system is *signed* and when promoted to `int` it will be sign-extended (according to the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) rules)

To solve the first point you need to discard the "leading" zero bytes.

To solve the second point you need to loop from the *end* (but only on little-endian systems).

To solve the third point use a type which won't be sign-extended (i.e. `uint8_t`).

Put together you could do something like this:

```
// The number we want to print
int port = 1234;

// Copy the raw binary data to a buffer
// This buffer is to not break strict aliasing
uint8_t _port[sizeof port];
memcpy(_port, &port, sizeof port);

// Skip leading zeroes in the buffer
// This is done by looping from the end of the buffer to the beginning,
// and loop as long as the current byte is zero
uint8_t *current;
for (current = _port + sizeof _port - 1; current > _port && *current == 0; --current)
{
    // Empty
}

// Print the remaining bytes
for (; current >= _port; --current)
{
    printf("\\x%02x", *current);  // Print with zero-padding, so e.g. \x4 becomes \x04
}
```

[Proof of concept](https://ideone.com/J7I8FZ)

Comment: Works like a charm, i justs need some time to look at it to understand what you have done :P Thank you!

Comment: @JanedOE I recommend you draw the "array" on paper, and draw an arrow to where `current` is pointing. Then erase and redraw the arrow as you "loop".

Comment: I thought about turning the loop du decrement but i was confused of typing, compiling, trying .. all at the same time. So current is just a pointer at what position the loop is on the integer, right? and you went from right to left and  jumped over the zeros and just displayed the higher order bytes on the left of your drawing??

Comment: @JanedOE Something like that yes. :)

Comment: Just one more question: on all x86/x86_64 systems? Also on linux or does the OS also makes a difference?

Comment: "wrong endian" would be directly solved by avoiding this `uint8_t *current;` and instead shifting `port` by 0 and then 8.

Comment: @JanedOE Endianness is CPU dependent, not OS dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of signess and modify the formats.

```
void foo(int port, int endianess)
{
    unsigned char * _port = (unsigned char*)&port;

    if(endianess)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
        {
            printf("\\x%02hhx", _port[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (size_t i = sizeof(port) - 1; i >= sizeof(port) - 2; i--) 
        {
            printf("\\x%02hhx", _port[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This way i get this output: \xd2\x04\x00\x00 - 2 nibbles (00) too much, not what i wanted :S  http://tpcg.io/2BD1Lr

Comment: Your link shows the same formatting and not the one i need! I need \xd2\x04 and not \xd2\x04\x00\x00

Comment: @JanedOE so change sizeof to 2 and you will have exactly two bytes displayed. Not too difficult.

Comment: You missed the same point like i did, endianess :S take a look at "Some programmers dude"'s answer

Comment: @JanedOE if you want to take the endianess into the account see my updated answer.

Comment: I already have had accepted "Some programmers Dude"s answer, he also explained it very well and i cant give points (less reputation) because i always have to create new accounts because being blocked for poor language and programming skills from some Pro's here :P